# setResult doesn't return to call onActivityResult after first time

Tags: java, android, android-activity, realm

I'm having some problems with onActivityResult. I have 2 activities, LoginActivity and MainActivity. MainActivity is the launch activity. OnCreate, it checks if there's a logged in user, if not it starts LoginActivity with startActivityForResult(). When a user successfully logs in, the setResult() and afterwards finish() method is called on LoginActivity. This triggers onActivityResult on MainActivity. Everything works fine.

However, I have logout button in MainActivity. If clicked, it removes the current user's session and again calls startActivityForResult and starts LoginActivity. Same flow, only after calling setResult() and finish() on LoginActivity this time MainActivity isn't shown (the app moves to the background) and onActivityResult() isn't called. Only when I manually bring the app to the foreground is onActivityResult() called. What gives?

Why is onActivityResult being called the first time I log in but not the second?

Manifest snippet:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

LoginActivity snippet:

```
/**
     * Saves the logged in session in the db and creates a UserModel if it's a new user logging in
     * @param intent
     */
    private void saveSession(Intent intent) {

        Session session = intent.getParcelableExtra(Session.SESSION);
        User user = session.getUser();

        realm.beginTransaction();

        //Check if user exists in db
        UserModel userModel = realm.where(UserModel.class).equalTo(PATIENT_ID, session.getUser().getPatientId()).findFirst();

        if(userModel == null) {
            userModel = new UserModel();
            userModel.setLanguage(user.getLanguage());
            userModel.setLastLogin(user.getLastLogin());
            userModel.setPatientId(user.getPatientId());
            userModel.setPermissions(new RealmList<RealmString>());
            for(int i = 0;user.getPermissions().size()>i;i++) {
                RealmString realmString = new RealmString();
                realmString.setValue(user.getPermissions().get(i));
                userModel.getPermissions().add(realmString);
            }
            userModel.setRegistered(user.getRegistered());
            userModel.setRole(user.getRole());
            userModel.setUserName(user.getUserName());
        }
        UserSessionModel userSession = new UserSessionModel();
        userSession.setUser(userModel);
        userSession.setCookie(session.getCookie());
        userSession.setJwt(session.getJwt());
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userSession);

        realm.commitTransaction();


        mJwt = session.getJwt();


        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra(LoginActivity.JWT, mJwt);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        super.finish();
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
/**
     * Show all the accounts registered on the device.
     * If there are no accounts, start LoginActivity to create one.
     */
    private void getAccount() {

        //Get all accounts
        final RealmResults<UserModel> availableAccounts = realm.where(UserModel.class).findAll();
        if(availableAccounts.size() == 0) {
            //Open login activity if there are no accounts
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            this.startActivityForResult(intent, AUTHENTICATE);
        } else if (availableAccounts.size() > 0) {
            availableAccounts.sort("lastLogin", Sort.DESCENDING);
            UserModel account = availableAccounts.get(0);
            getSession(account);
        }
    }

/**
     * Get an authentication token
     */
    private void getSession(UserModel account) {
        UserSessionModel result = realm.where(UserSessionModel.class)
                .equalTo("user.patientId", account.getPatientId())
                .findFirst();

        if(result != null) {
            init(result);
        } else {
            //Authenticate existing account
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.PATIENT_ID, account.getPatientId());
            this.startActivityForResult(intent, AUTHENTICATE);
        }
    }
```

Logout in MainActivity

```
/**
     * Logout and return to login view
     */
    private void logout() {
        showProgress(true);
        mLogoutTask = new UserLogoutTask(mSession.getCookie());
        if(mSession !=null) {
            realm.beginTransaction();
            mSession.deleteFromRealm();
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
        mLogoutTask.execute();
        mSession = null;
        getAccount();
    }
```

OnActivityResult in MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case AUTHENTICATE:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    String jwt = bundle.getString(LoginActivity.JWT);
                    UserSessionModel session = realm.where(UserSessionModel.class).equalTo("jwt", jwt).findFirst();
                    init(session);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Init method

```
private void init(final UserSessionModel session) {

        mSession = session;

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        lblUsername = ButterKnife.findById(headerView, R.id.header_username);
        // Set username in menu header
        lblUsername.setText(getString(R.string.welcome, mSession.getUser().getUserName()));

        Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(mSession.getUser().getPatientId());

        //Need to do this for the following code because Realm only allows access to object in the same threads
        final String patientId = mSession.getUser().getPatientId();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MRESIST_LOCATION_PERMISSION_CHANGED);
        } else {
            startGPSService();
        }

        //Start sensor service
        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                sensorServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SensorService.class);
                sensorServiceIntent.putExtra("patientId", patientId);
                getApplicationContext().startService(sensorServiceIntent);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: you should also add a snippet for `onActivityResult()` method in your MainActivity

Comment: Thx, added the onActivityResult snippet!

Comment: well nothing suspicious here. I'm curious what your `init` method does.

Comment: Added that as well ;)

Comment: your code is actually pretty clean, i can not determine the problem from your provided snippets. I see you don't have declared any `launchMode` for your `MainActivity`. Did you declare a launchMode for your `LoginActivity`?

Comment: No, haven't used launchMode. Should I?

Comment: No, but this could have been a cause for your problem,when using a launchMode like singleInstance. Do you use the method `moveTaskToBack()` in your `MainActivity`?  I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: I found the problem. The issue was in the UserLogoutTask I called in logout(). It's an AsyncTask that calls finish onPostExecute. Because I didn't wait for the result, it executed after LoginActivity was already show. Silly me. :) Thx for all the help!